# Updating a Reusable Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, office-365

I have a Reusable Workflow that is associated to a List. I would like to tweak this workflow and continue using it. Solutions that require a one-time migration (e.g. using a different type of work flow) are acceptable IF they provide this functionality in the future.

If I edit the Reusable Workflow and Publish it, the changes are not propagated to the associated list. If this "just worked," that would be the ideal solution. **[A] Is there any way for Publish to propagate Reusable Workflow changes to an associated list?**

There are various [articles](http://fahadzia.com/blog/2010/06/upgradingversioning-sharepoint-workflow-solution/) listing these solutions, but they are all for SP2010:

1. Wait for all workflow items to end. Delete existing workflow. Re-associate workflow.
2. Terminate all workflow items. Delete existing workflow. Re-associate workflow.
3. Version workflows (wf_v1, wf_v2) and continue adding a new workflow for every change.
4. Update/replace workflow file directly using PowerShell.

None of these 4 solutions seem feasible except #3. Manually versioning the workflow is possible, but it means losing the workflow history & tasks for each item. This also lends itself to the Approval Status being spread across 3-4 different columns. **[B] Is there a way to preserve Tasks, History, and Status Column when versioning a workflow?**

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I could never find a solution to this SharePoint bug. We ended up using a List Workflow instead of a Reusable Workflow. The List Workflow can be updated simply by Publishing.

Answer (score 1):

Opening and saving the settings for the workflow association seems to update the workflow to the latest published version, when re-publishing the reusable workflow isn't working.

To do this:

1. Open the *Workflow Settings* page for list or library you're having problems with
2. Choose the name of the workflow from the list
3. Click **OK** at the bottom of the *Change a Workflow* page